# How can I show the next questions in my quiz bot and fix the error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a quiz through my discord bot where when I react to the first question it pushes in its respective array the number value and then shows the next question. I tried with a "for" but it shows all the questions without the reaction.

I made this code but when I react it shows this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #
> (node:73631) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:73631) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How could I solve the error and show the next question when I react?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('../src/structures/client');
module.exports = {
 name: `quiz`,
 aliases: 'q',
 /**
  * @param {Client} client
  * @param {Message} message
  * @param {String[]} args
  */
 run: async (client, message, args) => {
  const pregunta = [
   'Do you smoke?',
   'Do you drink alcohol?',
   'Do you read books?',
  ];
  const respuestas = `1 ) Nunca
        2 ) Casi nunca
        3 ) A veces
        4 ) Usualmente
        5 ) Siempre`;
  const time = 10;
  var autoconciencia = []; //0.4.8.11.14.
  var autogestion = []; //2.5.9.12.17.
  var concienciasocial = []; //3.6.13.16.18.
  var relaciones = []; //1.7.10.15.19.
  var i = 0;

  function pusharrays(reaction, array) {
   switch (reaction) {
    case '1️⃣':
     array.push(1);
     break;
    case '2️⃣':
     array.push(2);
     break;
    case '3️⃣':
     array.push(3);
     break;
    case '4️⃣':
     array.push(4);
     break;
    case '5️⃣':
     array.push(5);
     break;
   }
  }
  message.channel
   .send(
    new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setAuthor(`Question: ${pregunta[i]}`, message.client.user.avatarURL)
     .setDescription(`${respuestas}`)
     .setColor('#ffdb26')
   )
   .then(async (msg) => {
    await msg.react('1️⃣');
    await msg.react('2️⃣');
    await msg.react('3️⃣');
    await msg.react('4️⃣');
    await msg.react('5️⃣');
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
     return (
      ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot
     );
    };
    msg
     .awaitReactions(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: time * 1000,
      errors: ['time'],
     })
     .then((collected) => {
      var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name;
      var challanger = collected.first().users.cache.last();
      console.log(reaction);
      if (reaction) {
       if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 11 || i == 14) {
        pusharrays(reaction, autoconciencia);
        console.log('array_1: ' + autoconciencia);
        i++;
       } else if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 9 || i == 12 || i == 17) {
        pusharrays(reaction, autogestion);
        console.log('array_2: ' + autogestion);
        i++;
       } else if (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 16 || i == 18) {
        pusharrays(reaction, concienciasocial);
        console.log('array_3: ' + concienciasocial);
        i++;
       } else if (i == 1 || i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 15 || i == 19) {
        pusharrays(reaction, relaciones);
        console.log('array_4: ' + relaciones);
        i++;
       }
      }
     });
   });
 },
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('../src/structures/client');
module.exports = {
 name: `quiz`,
 aliases: 'q',
 /**
  * @param {Client} client
  * @param {Message} message
  * @param {String[]} args
  */

 run: async (client, message, args) => {
  const preguntas = [
   'Do you smoke?',
   'Do you drink alcohol?',
   'Do you read books?',
  ];
  const respuestas = `1 ) Nunca
        2 ) Casi nunca
        3 ) A veces
        4 ) Usualmente
        5 ) Siempre`;
  const time = 10;
  var autoconciencia = []; //0.4.8.11.14.
  var autogestion = []; //2.5.9.12.17.
  var concienciasocial = []; //3.6.13.16.18.
  var relaciones = []; //1.7.10.15.19.

  var i = 0;

  function pusharrays(reaction, array) {
   switch (reaction) {
    case '1️⃣':
     array.push(1);
     break;
    case '2️⃣':
     array.push(2);
     break;
    case '3️⃣':
     array.push(3);
     break;
    case '4️⃣':
     array.push(4);
     break;
    case '5️⃣':
     array.push(5);
     break;
   }
  }

  nextquestion(i);

  function nextquestion(i) {
   if (i < preguntas.length) {
    message.channel
     .send(
      new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setAuthor(`Question: ${preguntas[i]}`, message.client.user.avatarURL)
       .setDescription(`${respuestas}`)
       .setColor('#ffdb26')
     )
     .then(async (msg) => {
      await msg.react('1️⃣');
      await msg.react('2️⃣');
      await msg.react('3️⃣');
      await msg.react('4️⃣');
      await msg.react('5️⃣');

      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
       return (
        ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
        !user.bot
       );
      };

      msg
       .awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: time * 1000,
        errors: ['time'],
       })
       .then((collected) => {
        var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name;
        var challanger = collected.first().users.cache.last();
        console.log(reaction);
        if (reaction) {
         if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 11 || i == 14) {
          pusharrays(reaction, autoconciencia);
          console.log('array_1: ' + autoconciencia);
          i++;
          nextquestion(i);
         } else if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 9 || i == 12 || i == 17) {
          pusharrays(reaction, autogestion);
          console.log('array_2: ' + autogestion);
          i++;
          nextquestion(i);
         } else if (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 16 || i == 18) {
          pusharrays(reaction, concienciasocial);
          console.log('array_3: ' + concienciasocial);
          i++;
          nextquestion(i);
         } else if (i == 1 || i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 15 || i == 19) {
          pusharrays(reaction, relaciones);
          console.log('array_4: ' + relaciones);
          i++;
          nextquestion(i);
         }
        }
       });
     });
   } else console.log('FIN CUESTIONARIO');
  }
 },
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.